# C pass char as reference

Tags: c++, c

when i use this code, the program aborted after inserting first char
when i delete the star(*) inside the function it works but it becomes as C++ referencing . I want to keep it pure (C)

```
void info(char *first, char *second, char *third)
{
    printf("insert three char: ");

    scanf(" %c %c %c", *first,*second,*third);
}
int main()
{
    char a=' ',b=' ',c=' ';

    info(&a,&b,&c);
}
```

Comment: You're meant to use `&` to pass a pointer to something. Use `scanf("...", &first, &second, &third)`

Comment: This is pure C. Your code has no references at all.

Comment: @Arc676 You don't need to use `&`. `first`, `second`, and `third` are already pointers. Using `&` will pass `scanf` a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: There is no pass by reference in C, as in C the term "*reference*" has no well defined meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your scanf it will work and it is in pure c

```
scanf(" %c %c %c", first, second, third);
```

and you can't do like `*first` because in scanf it required address of variable so it is aborting after insert of first char in your case.

In function you are passing addresses and not reference.

Answer (score 3):

Without `*(valueof)` operator in `scanf` its pure C:

To explain your concept try using three pointers :

```
void info(char *first, char *second, char *third)
{
    printf("insert three char: ");

    scanf(" %c %c %c", first,second,third);
}
int main()
{
    char a=' ',b=' ',c=' ';
    char *p1=&a;
    char *p2=&b;
    char *p3=&c;
    info(p1,p2,p3);
    return 0;
}
```

which was just equalvalent to passing **addresses** `info(&a,&b,&c)` and not **reference**.